# How can i remove every character before a specific character in a tuple of lists of strings in Python

Tags: python

I have a tuple of lists of strings that looks like this

`myList = ['https://wwww.example.com/watch/random-video-12'], ['https://wwww.example.com/watch/random-video-t-14'], ['https://www.example.com/watch/random-video-longest-1']`

and i need to remove the last "-" character and every character before that.

Comment: Better add the expected output, at least

Comment: Something like `[x.split("-")[-1] for x in myList]`?

Comment: Your list has brackets in the middle of it? That looks like a set of three lists...

Comment: Beside the point, but that's not a list of strings, it's a tuple of lists of strings.

Comment: @JNevill It's a `tuple`, not a `set`, but you're using the word "set" in the non-technical sense, eh?

Comment: What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? Do you know regex, for example?  For more tips, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = []
for url in myList:
    result.append(url[0].split('-')[-1])
print(result)
```

**Outputs** :

```
['12', '14', '1']
```

**Explanation** :

`url` is a list that has a single element, `url[0]`. Applying `split('-')` on that string split the string into a list of strings that were separated with '-'.
ie : `'https://wwww.example.com/watch/random-video-12'.split('-') -> ['https://wwww.example.com/watch/random', 'video', '12']`.
Finally `list[-1]` gives the last element of `list`

Comment: Simpler to use a list comprehension: `result = [url[0]... for url in myList]`

Comment: This fails if any url does not contain '-'

Answer (score 0):

The variable *myList* is not a list as its name might imply. It's actually a tuple of lists where each list contains just one element. Therefore:

```
myList = ['https://wwww.example.com/watch/randomvideo-12'], ['https://wwww.example.com/watch/random-video-t-14'], ['https://www.example.com/watch/random-video-longest-1']

for list_ in myList:
    for url in list_:
        if len(t := url.split('-')) > 1:
            print(t[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
12
14
1
```

**Note:**

The inner *for* loop isn't actually necessary for these data but is there to allow for extension of the lists

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str.split` you could use `str.rsplit` and do it all in a comprehension:

```
[url[0].rsplit('-', 1)[1] for urls in myList if '-' in url[0])]
```

---

```
['12', '14', '1']
```